# Ax Trace Parser Doesnt Show SQL Queries

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Configuring the tracing cockpit to show sql events, traceparser doesn't show the sql tab, how can I get the sql queries from trace parser?

And one second question, It also shows only my queries,is there a way to make it show all queries running in ax?

Answer (score 0):

See how to [Install the Trace Parser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731935.aspx).
Also ensure you run it from the AOS server and that [the correct event selection](http://junctionsolutions.com/blogjuice/dynamics-ax-2012-trace-parser-setup/) is provided.

Also start AX with escalated privileges (Run as administrator).

Comment: From the look of it,everything looks the way things should be,Trace Parser is installed properly with proper connection to AOS server,and event selection looks normal as well :(

Comment: Did you install TP on the SQL Server? Not sure, but I remember I had to install on SQL, AOS and client ...

Comment: Also your problem may be permission related, check logs.

Comment: Looks like I needed a server session to see the trace logs.