# Traceparser and the SQL tab

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009, etw

I have used Dynamics AX Traceparser on a number of occasions and usually without issues. This time however I can't seem to manage to generate and AX ETW trace that will show SQL in my TraceParser.

I can confirm it's not because I didn't load a server session, so it's not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885431/ax-trace-parser-doesnt-show-sql-queries).

Things I have tried:

1. I looked in the traceparser database, there is not a single query in there
2. I did the whole run as administrator thing
3. I verified registry settings
4. I started tracing from both server config and client config.
5. I tried converting the .trc file to an xml file using `tracerpt` but the resulting xml doesn't make much sense.
6. I tried deactivating the `DATAAREAIDLITERALS` in `SQLSYSTEMSETTINGS`

Things that are different/uncommon about this environment

1. I can't install the client and traceparser on the AOS itself
2. AX Build 5.0.1600.2967 has been installed (incorporating the `DATAAREAIDLITERALS` change) because this customer has a lot of parameter sniffing issues.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the issue?
Has anyone tested traces on an AX with that specific patch (as I can imagine the query generation change could affect the trace .mof configuration)

If anyone can suggest me of a way to verify if the trace actually contains SQL information that would be of help too, because now I have no clue if the tracing fails or the importing.

Comment: Hi Tom, Is it only SQL or all server side trace? Please verify that the account which is used as AOS service accout has local administrator. If 5.0.1600.2967 build is the latest one that allows to do parameter sniffing for dataAreaId I have used trace parser with it without any issues